# Creating two columns in beamer

Tags: beamer, columns

I have searched the stackexchange for a resolution of this problem, but I am still getting an error message when I put in the following (for now neglecting other things in my document, such as documentclass, begin{document}, etc.):

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{explanation}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{width=0.5\textwidth}
   some text here
\end{column}
\begin{column}
    \begin{center}
     \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image1.jpg}      
     \end{center}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

When compiled, I get the error: `Missing number, treated as zero`. I should appreciate any help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You don't need to use `width=`, you just enter the width directly.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You forgot to give the mandatory width to the second column, and you included an unnecessary `width=` in the width for the first column.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
\frametitle{explanation}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}  %%<--- here
    \begin{center}
     \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image1.jpg}
     \end{center}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: am I the only one for whom the columns are not aligned horizontally?

Comment: In Overleaf I had to set an explicit width for both columns

Answer (score 14):

Also note that the graphics need not be scaled down as much in the second column. The column becomes a `minipage`, so `\textwidth` is already adjusted to its width.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
\frametitle{explanation}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
   some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}  
    \begin{center}
     %%%%% this is a minipage, so \textwidth is already adjusted to the size of the column
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1.jpg}
     \end{center}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

The "columns" feature of Beamer (other answers above) lets you customize the layout and the breaking point.

However if you want to let the text flow or you don't care about the exact layout, many times the good old `multicol` package does the job well with less noise.
Paragraph divisions and `\columnbreak` can help deciding what is on the left and side or the right hand side in the two-column case.

```
\usepackage{multicol}
...
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{multicols}{2} % two columns
        Left Hand side text

        \includegraphics[width=4cm]{RHS_image}
    \end{multicols}
\end{frame}
```