# Beamer: Graphic outside the frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, two-column

No matter what I have done (change the axis limits, scale, resize the witdh of the colums) the graph is always outside

```
\begin{frame}\frametitle{test}
\begin{block}{}
D $x^2+4y^2-6x+16y+21=0$,
\end{block}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{6cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item$x^2-6x+4y^2+16y=-21$
\item$x^2-6x+9-9+4y^2+16y=-21$
\item$(x-3)^2-9+4(y^2+4y+4-4)=-21$
\item$(x-3)^2-9+4(y+2)^2-16=-21$
\item$(x-3)^2+4(y+2)^2=-21+9+16=4$
\item$\frac{(x-3)^{2}+4(y+2)^{2}}{4}=\frac{4}{4}=1$
\item$\frac{(x-3)^{2}}{4}+\frac{(y+2)^{2}}{1}=1$



\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{6cm}
\linebreak
\linebreak
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            axis line style={->},
        },
    marya/.style={color=green,thick,mark=none},
    soldot/.style={color=green,only marks,mark=*},
    holdot/.style={color=green,fill=white,only marks,mark=*},
    grid style={dotted,gray},
}

\tikzset{>=stealth}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            grid=both,
            axis equal,
            xmin=0,xmax=5,
            ymin=-4,ymax=0,
            {scale=0.75}
        ]
        \draw[marya,domain=-3:6,samples=50] (3,-2) ellipse (2 and 1);
        \addplot[soldot]coordinates {(-15,0)} node [anchor=north west,text=black]  {$f$};
        \addplot[soldot]coordinates {(15,0)} node [anchor=north west,text=black]  {$f$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushleft}
ss
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

What can be done in order to appear completely in the column space?

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 and provide a better question in the future. Even the tag `beamer` is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all, your code example is not suitable for others to help you. This is not your first question --> please read and follow [this post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).
- I guesstimate what you want to achieve and provide a clean example.
- Related: [Creating two columns in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228271)

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frametitle}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item
                \item Item
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                    width = 1.0\textwidth,
                    xlabel = $x$,
                    ylabel = {$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$},
                    ]
                \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]