Insert arbitrary-row-size multi-columns in revtex4, for the purpose of inserting figures more freely
Are there equivalent commands in revtex4 documentclass, like the multi columns inserted in the arbitrary place in the beamer like the following?
Naively, I expect something like this so we can insert texts or figures in the arbitrary row size multi-columns:
        \documentclass[aps,pra,10pt,nofootinbib]{revtex4}
    \begin{document}
      \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.25\textwidth}
ABC\\
123
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.75\textwidth}
EFG\\
456
        \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{document}

But the above command does not work. Ideally, we like to present figures (\includegraphics) or text in this manner:


You could use minipages (that's what beamer columns are under the hood)

p.s. the beamer example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228272/41144

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, Thanks can you upgrade to a complete answer!

@ wonderich done! :)

If you want more flexibility than a rectangular layout, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz usually recommends picture mode such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213293/1090

@DavidCarlisle Arrange images in an airplane shape? Very creative!

You could use minipages, that's what beamer uses under the hood for columns:
\documentclass[aps,pra,10pt,nofootinbib]{revtex4}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[T][8cm][t]{0.225\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%
  \vfill
  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[T]{0.725\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}


